# Bulk copy files from network to virtual machine command

Tags: ubuntu, scp, remote

I need to copy all the files and folders from my company's network folder (of another employees) to my virtual machine.

For example

Source:  `\\ABCCL001569\Code\`

Destination: `/var/www/html/code_Dump`

1. Is this possible scp? If so how?
2. Once copied to `/var/www/html/code_Dump` I need to move the entire list of files and directories to `/var/www/html/another_location`

Comment: `cp`, `rsync` `scp`... take your pick!

Comment: i need via scp or rsync.... im trying something like scp \\ABCCL001569\\Code root@10.20.30.40:/var/www/html/code_Dump ... i know source path would be meaningless,cause im writing this command in VM and its not accessible to other employees network drive...want a proper command

Comment: so the VM does not have access to the \\ABCCL001569\Code\ ?

Comment: What is the remote computer? Windows, OS X, *nix?

Comment: Remote computer is Windows 7 @Zachary

Comment: In my system I have access to my VM, the network drive is in another computer@mazs

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to first mount the share of the windows computer with a command like below.

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=${USER},password=${PASSWORD} //server-address/share /mount/path/on/ubuntu
```

So a completed command might look like.

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=MyUsername,password=SecretPassword //ABCCL001569/Code /mnt/cifs
```

Then you will can copy and move files all you want via `cp` or `rsync`

```
cp -vr /mount/path/on/ubuntu /var/www/html/code_Dump
```

Comment: Ok let me try tat... And what's the username and password.. Of my remote computer?  if so how do I get those

Comment: The username and password are for the share on `ABCCL001569`. You get them by asking whoever has access to the computer/share. But based on your comment I am guessing you don't know if there is even an available share on the remote computer. Do you have access to the windows computer?

Comment: Yes I have access to the network folder,  copy files  from network drive to my computer hard drive...tat code folder was shared to me from another employee... We can copy the files from Windows to windows... Wat I wanted to try was copy those huge size files from tat network folder to my VM ubuntu thru cmd... But no idea if we can get the password for the shared folder

Comment: So when you access from windows to windows I assume you're using a UNC path or something like that to access `ABCCL001569` and it's share for `Code`. You use the same username and password for that. I also removed the `uid=,gid=` bit as it was a unnecessary.

Comment: Ok basically ABCCL001569 is within the organizations domain... Different network for different emp... We do ctrl c ctrl v from tat abc network to our local hard drive... This takes hell lot of time since Windows... So let me see if is it possible to get tat remotes ABCs network password details...

Comment: Hey @Zachary, i created a symlink from remote computer of another person to my local like mklink /d "Local_source_path" "\\ABCCL001569\Code\"...and then copied from local to remote VM using scp...  its copying now..thanks